# How to Set up Visual Studio Code to Debug Requests with python and Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache, visual-studio-code

> Python:3.3.5
>
> Django: 1.8
>
> IDE: VSCode
>
> Server: Apache 2.4
>
> Mod_wsgi:4.4.6
>
> Test tool: Postman

My project like this:

> /A
>
> /B
>
> /subfolder
>
> test.py
>
> manage.py
>
> settings.py

---

launch.json:

```
    {
    "name": "Django test",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "pythonPath": "C:/Python33/python.exe",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/B/manage.py",
    "args": [
        "runserver",
        "--noreload",
        "--nothreading"
    ],
    // "debugOptions": [
    //     "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
    //     "WaitOnNormalExit",
    //     "RedirectOutput",
    //     "DjangoDebugging"
    // ],
    "django": true
},
```

manage.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

---

I try to set a breakpoint at test.py but not working,
it cannot stop at the breakpoint,
I ensure the server is running and test.py can work,
and terminal output doesn't show an error message.

When I used postman to post, the status is 200 and test .py return my string `ok`.

Comment: What happens if you open VS Code at your folder B?

Comment: @BrettCannon Nothing happened...same situation.

Comment: Feel free to open an issue at github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd then.